# Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ is bounded

Tags: limits, functions

> Let $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a function given by:
>   $$
> f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}&\text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0),\\
> 0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0).
> \end{cases}
> $$

I need to show that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R^2$, so I need to show that there exists $M>0:\vert f(x,y)\vert\leq M$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

We can rewrite $\begin{align}f(x,y)=\frac{x/y^2}{1+(x/y^2)^2}=\frac{z}{1+z^2}\end{align}$, where $z=x/y^2$ (and $y\neq0$).

So for $z$ large enough, our expression will go to 0. Now we only need to worry for the case that $z$ approaches 0. We rewrite again: $\begin{align}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1/z+z}\end{align}$, so $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1}{1/z+z}=0$. Whatever $(x,y)$ do, if their values get small enough, we see that $f(x,y)$ will get arbitrarily close to zero, en if their values get big enough, $f(x,y)$ also comes arbitrarily close to zero.

However, this can't be true, because $f(cy^2,y)=\frac{c}{1+c^2}$, so the function isn't even continuous on 0 to begin with. I'm stuck; can someone help me with this?

Comment: It's a duplicate, by the way it can be solved using AM-GM inequality

Comment: Note that the function need not to be continuous to be bounded, you seem to imply that continuity is needed in your last statement.

Comment: You can try making the next variable change $a=x^2$ and $b=y^4$ and therefore by AM-GM your function is always less or equal than $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @zwim Yea, I think I got confused, because I thought that $z\to0$ meant that $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, but that is of course not true. We are simply considering the fraction $z=x/y^2$, and say what happens to the function when the fraction is $>1$ and when $\leq 1$ (I got that from the answer below:p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z>1$, then $z^2 > z$

If $ z \le 1$, then $z \le 1 + z^2$ since $z^2 > 0$

So your function $f(z)$ is always $f(z)\le 1$ hence bounded

Comment: But don't  you have to show that $|f(z)|$ is less than $1$?

Comment: @TheCrypticCat How about writing it like this: For $z>1$, we have that $0<f(x,y)<1$. For $z\in[-1,1]$, we have that $-1<f(x,y)<1$. For $z<1$, we have that $\vert z\vert<\vert 1+z^2\vert$, so $\vert f(x,y)\vert<1$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $a=x^2$ and $b=y^4$. By AM-GM we have 
$$\sqrt{ab} \le \frac{a+b}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{ab}}{a+b} \le \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}\le \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

- Consider $(z+1)^2 \geq0$. This leads to $\Large \frac{z}{z^2+1}$$\geq-$$\Large\frac{1}{2}$.
- Now take  $(z-1)^2 \geq0$ This yields $\Large \frac{z}{z^2+1}$$\leq$$\Large\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore $\large f $ is bounded.